# Laravel PHP for loops and if statements

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, if-statement

Currently trying to build a for loop to read through my $userSkills array and then using an if statement to print out specific text based on it.

This is how the code looks like

```
@for ($x = 1; $x < $skillCount; $x++) {
    @if($userSkills[$x] = '{ 66; }')
        <span>Hi</span>
    @else
        <span>{{$userSkills[$x]}}</span>
    @endif                        
}
@endfor
```

And in my array it would be {AA, 66, 67, 69}
So I wanted to make it print out as such

```
Hi 67 69
```

However the output looks like this

```
{ Hi } { Hi } { Hi }
```

Comment: `@if($userSkills[$x] = '{ 66; }')` should be `@if($userSkills[$x] == '{ 66; }')`

Answer (score 2):

A single equal sign is an assignment so what you're doing in the if parens is setting `$userSkills[$x]` equal to `'{ 66; }'` which will evaluate to true so the if block is executed. You'll want to use either a double equals sign to check if the value is the same or a triple equals sign to test for the same value and the same type.

Also, `$userSkills[1]` will be equal to `66` rather than `'{ 66; }'` and arrays are 0 based so you'll want to change `$x = 1` to `$x = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

please try the code below:

```
@foreach ($userSkills as $userSkill)
 <span>
  {!! $userSkill == 66 ? 'HI' : $userSkill !!}
 </span>
@endforeach
```